# Customers that bought in 2017 but did not buy in 2016

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables: customers, orders
How to find all customers that bought ìtem = 'A' or item = 'B' in the year 2017 but did not buy neither item = 'A' ñor item = 'B' in the year 2016.

How could the SQL look like?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It depends how the two tables are linked. We need sample data and/table structures

Comment: show table structure and sample data and expected out put.  also helpful if you actually try and then post your code - this is not a 'do it for me' site

Comment: What have you tried so far????

Comment: The key oracle keyword is `minus`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be something like:

```
SELECT c.id
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN orders o ON c.id = o.customer_id
WHERE o.item IN ('A', 'B')
AND YEAR(o.date) = 2017
AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1
 FROM order o2
 WHERE o2.item IN ('A', 'B')
 AND YEAR(o2.date) = 2016
 AND o2.customer_id = o.customer_id)
```

This depends on your table structure. But basically you want to find the customers that have purchased item A or B in 2017 in the main query. Then the NOT EXISTS clause checks that the same customer did not buy A or B in the previous year.

Comment: Would the solution work with large tables?

Comment: It will work, but like many people have said, we can give you a better solution if you provide the table and column names and sample data.